# How to duplicate a first and last line in pandas from a block that have matching block values?

Tags: python, database, pandas

In the following data:

```
block  M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 H0 H1 S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8                                                      
151    A  T  T  A  A  G  A  C  A  C  C  G  C  T  T  A  G  A
151    T  G  C  T  G  T  T  G  T  A  A  T  A  T  C  A  A  T
151    C  A  A  C  A  G  T  C  C  G  G  A  C  G  C  G  C  G
155    G  T  G  T  A  T  C  T  G  T  C  T  T  T  A  T  C  T
155    C  A  A  C  A  G  T  C  C  G  G  A  C  G  C  G  C  G
155    A  T  T  A  A  G  A  C  A  C  C  G  C  T  T  A  G  A
155    A  G  A  C  A  C  C  C  G  G  A  C  G  C  T  A  T  C
```

I want to duplicate the first and last lines for each block without giving values `151` and `155` such that lines are duplicated whenever they have a matching block values.

**Output:**

```
block  M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6 M7 M8 H0 H1 S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6 S7 S8                                                      
151    A  T  T  A  A  G  A  C  A  C  C  G  C  T  T  A  G  A
151    A  T  T  A  A  G  A  C  A  C  C  G  C  T  T  A  G  A
151    T  G  C  T  G  T  T  G  T  A  A  T  A  T  C  A  A  T
151    C  A  A  C  A  G  T  C  C  G  G  A  C  G  C  G  C  G
151    C  A  A  C  A  G  T  C  C  G  G  A  C  G  C  G  C  G
155    G  T  G  T  A  T  C  T  G  T  C  T  T  T  A  T  C  T
155    G  T  G  T  A  T  C  T  G  T  C  T  T  T  A  T  C  T
155    C  A  A  C  A  G  T  C  C  G  G  A  C  G  C  G  C  G
155    A  T  T  A  A  G  A  C  A  C  C  G  C  T  T  A  G  A
155    A  G  A  C  A  C  C  C  G  G  A  C  G  C  T  A  T  C
155    A  G  A  C  A  C  C  C  G  G  A  C  G  C  T  A  T  C
```

Comment: I think you meant 155 for last 3 lines of your input. Is your data in a pandas.DataFrame?

Comment: oh yeah. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate each sub data frame with its first and last row after grouping the original data frame by *block*:

```
df.groupby('block', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: pd.concat([g.head(1), g, g.tail(1)]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. **post edit:** what if I have some of the block represented as `.` or `None` for which I don't want to duplicate the lines.

Comment: Do you have missing values in the block or they are represented by another string such as `.`? Normally adding an if else in the lambda expression should be good.

Comment: They are `.` and some places may be empty string.

Comment: As long as they are not missing values, you can still use groupby with if else, for instance, `df.groupby('block', group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: pd.concat([g.head(1), g, g.tail(1)]) if g.block.iloc[0] not in [".", ""] else g)` This will insert rows if block is neither `.` nor empty string, otherwise don't make duplicates. You can add more edge cases in the list as you need.